# What does the firewall in ubuntu 20.04 do when i activate it?

Tags: firewall, ufw

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and found that the firewall is inactive.

Input:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

Output:

```
Status: inactive
```

- What is `verbose` and `ufw` ?
- Why is it not activated by default?
- What will it do when i activate it (how does it work basically)?

Answer (score 0):

`man ufw` will tell you what the ufw command is, and what it does, in the same way that the manual system does for most other programs.

That manual page also explains what the `status` option to `ufw` does. It doesn't say explicitly what the "verbose" output gives you, but I expect it will give more information than "status" would do by default otherwise, to help with diagnostics.

You should check whether the firewall is running (eg, using ps) and/or whether it is enabled or disabled in its configuration. You may need to edit the configuration, and enable the firewall (perhaps using `systemd`) to make it run automatically.

Comment: You can improve your answer by including the relevant information from the man page.

Comment: I would say that the rather general nature of the original question means that Read The Fine Manual, without quoting specifics from the manual, is the appropriate answer?